# TFS Datawarehouse Report with "Acceptance criteria"

Tags: tfs, sql-data-warehouse

We are using TFS 2018 and we'd like to generate SSRS report on the test cases linked to acceptance criteria.

Following are the issues:

1) Acceptance criteria field is not available in TFS_Datawarehouse.

2) Is there any recommended/best practices suggested by microsoft to track acceptance criteria for a user story being linked to test case?

Thanks,

Aruna

Answer (score 0):

As the `Acceptance Criteria` fields is not the reportable field in TFS Server, so we cannot get the field's data from TFS warehouse or analysis databases. Please see [Reportable fields reference for Visual Studio ALM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/reportable-fields-reference?view=vsts) for details.

You can try to create work item query to get your User Story work items and select the `Acceptance Criteria` column in query result to track it. Please see [Query by titles, IDs, and rich-text fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/titles-ids-descriptions?view=vsts) for details.